# Invalid error in Clion about using coroutines

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion

I'm testing coroutines in CLion on Windows with WSL toolchain (g++10) and I'm getting this error when using co_return statement:

```
Std::experimental::coroutine_traits type was not found; include <experimental/coroutine> before defining a coroutine
```

in editor - but everything compiles fine and working. The WSL toolchain is the only one in CLion. How can I remove/fix them?

Comment: IDEs sometimes flag (or fail to flag) errors when they shouldn't.  The parsing they use is less sophisticated than the compiler proper and hence more prone to making mistakes.  I doubt you can fix this.

Comment: Yes, but when I used a msvc compiler from windows (and std::experimental namespace), errors dissapears - so, its seems like it takes some rules from Windows, not from WSL

Comment: But that would use a different set of STL header files, no?  Maybe CLion's parser can cope with those.

Comment: Good idea, but no - according to Clion helper, after precisezing a compiler, it should copy headers

Comment: Does that make any difference?  MSVC and gcc use a different set of headers, however that is made to happen.

Comment: I checked on VirtualBox, its the same situation....

Comment: You mean you got a compiler error?  Could you post a link to that?

Comment: Nope, everything compiles fine, only in editor i see this error

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what you mean by "I checked on VirtualBox, its the same situation".